# C# mysql parameters, point column error

Tags: c#, mysql

Using the code I keep getting the error "Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field"  However, if i copy and paste the string into an MySQL editor the query runs fine.  Any thoughts?

```
string geoPOINTSTRING = splitZippy[4] + " " + splitZippy[5];
            string atGvar = "GeomFromText('Point(" + geoPOINTSTRING + ")');";
            string mySQLfinishedProcessing = " insert into zipcodes " +
              "set zipcode = '" + zipcodeString + "'" +
              ",State = '" + StateString + "'" +
              ",City = '" + CityString + "'" +
              ",GEOPoint = @g"+
            ",StateCode = '" + StateCodeString2 + "'";
MySqlConnection configCON = new MySqlConnection(SQLStringClass.zipCONString);
            MySqlCommand CounterLogs = new MySqlCommand(mySQLfinishedProcessing, configCON);
            CounterLogs.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g",(string)atGvar);
            configCON.Open();
            CounterLogs.ExecuteNonQuery();
            configCON.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are completely misusing parameters.

A parameter is a raw value.
You're setting `GEOPoint` to the literal **string** `GeomFromText('Point(something)');`

You need to put the actual values in parameters—`zipcodeString`, `StateString`, `CityString`, `geoPOINTSTRING`, and `StateCodeString2`.

You would then write `GEOPoint = GeomFromText(@pointString)`, where `pointString` is a parameter holding `"Point(" + geoPOINTSTRING + ")"`  (The string you want to pass to `GeomFromText`)